# How to find out the duration of a service uptime using powershell?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use Windows Powershell to obtain the start time of a specific process so that i can build some logic to take a decision if it should be restarted automatically or not.

I tried using the below commandlet in my script

`Get-Process|Select Name, StartTime;`

But this fetches me the times when it was restarted during the past two days and not the exact last restart time. Since the times that are displayed are random and not ordered it is tough to figure out the last restart from the values returned.

Comment: Do you mean `Get-Service` instead of `Get-Process`? `ServiceName` is only a property for `Get-Service`.

Comment: sorry that's my mistake. i'm trying to figure out uptime for one of the services that is running in windows server (services.msc) so yes it is a process up time

Comment: @AmarKarthiArasan - please edit your posted Question/code. it makes for a great deal of needless confusion if you leave the mix of `Service` and `Process` references. [*grin*]

Answer (score 3):

Use the `Win32_Service` WMI class to obtain the process ID of the process currently hosting the service, then query `Win32_Process` for the creation time:

```bsh
function Get-ServiceUptime
{
  param([string]$Name)

  # Prepare name filter for WQL
  $Name = $Name -replace "\\","\\" -replace "'","\'" -replace "\*","%"

  # Fetch service instance
  $Service = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Service -Filter "Name LIKE '$Name'"

  # Use ProcessId to fetch corresponding process
  $Process = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Process -Filter "ProcessId = $($Service.ProcessId)"

  # Calculate uptime and return
  return (Get-Date) - $Process.CreationDate
}
```

Now you can do:

```bsh
$uptime = Get-ServiceUptime -Name MyServiceName
# or
$uptime = Get-ServiceUptime -Name MyServiceN*
```

Comment: This does not work for services running in the process svchost. This process lives longer than the services.